# result of json dosn't display and no error shows up in php

Tags: php, json

i have a code in php that give result in json and there is no result when i tryed the php script on browser here's the php file and my mysql table

```
<?php 
    //Importing Database Script 
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //Creating sql query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM EnfantVaccin";

    //getting result 
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    //creating a blank array 
    $result = array();

    //looping through all the records fetched
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

        //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
        array_push($result,array(
            "enfant_vacc_id"=>$row['enfant_vacc_id'],
            "enfant_id"=>$row['enfant_id'],
            "nomVaccin"=>$row['nomVaccin'],
            "ageApproprie"=>$row['ageApproprie'],
            "etat"=>$row['etat'],
            "date_vaccin"=>$row['date_vaccin']
        ));
    }

    //Displaying the array in json format w samineh result itableau fi json format 5ater valeur mta3 notre TAG_JSON_ARRAY hia result
    echo json_encode(array('resultVaccinEnf'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);
```

and that's the  mysql table 'EnfantVaccin'

```
CREATE TABLE `EnfantVaccin`(
`enfant_vacc_id`  bigint(50) unsigned  NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `enfant_id` bigint(50) unsigned  NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
 `nomVaccin` varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
`ageApproprie` int(10) NOT NULL,
`etat` boolean NOt null ,/*ca indique si ce vaccin particulier est fait pour cet enfant particulier ou pas */
`date_vaccin` date not null,/*indique la date de ce vaccin pour cet enfant*/
PRIMARY KEY (`enfant_vacc_id`) ,
CONSTRAINT `FK_enf2` FOREIGN KEY (`enfant_id`) REFERENCES `enfant` (`enfant_id`)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and that's the rows i have in the table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMUhq.png)

i hope i can find help i am really confused

Comment: Does it output anything, or just a white screen. From the code you've provided I would expect at least some output.

Comment: a white screen i can send the result if you want

Comment: try adding  MYSQLI_ASSOC in your fetch_array syntax, `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){` that is the reason it does not work. I would propose using prepared statements though.

Comment: thanks i tried  MYSQLI_ASSOC but still white screen

Comment: @bigginerEngeneer You need to check your error logs and turn on error reporting. It sounds like you're potentially got a fatal error somewhere, but I don't think it's in the code you've provided.

Comment: @PeterDarmis Why would that make a difference? I don't think it would.

Comment: Yes it does @JonStirling . If by default `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches results like in `MYSQLI_NUM` mode meaning with numbers as keys in the array then how would you expect to get a value when looking for `$row['enfant_vacc_id']` when you should be looking for `$row[0]` ??  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: @bigginerEngeneer have you tried the full code??

Comment: @PeterDarmis Please read the documentation, the default is `MYSQLI_BOTH` so adding `MYSQLI_ASSOC` in this case makes zero difference wrt the code being run.

Comment: but there is no other code i used only this one and it gives white screen, the problem the same code work with an other table but not with this one so i said maybe there is some thing specific in this table i don't know

Comment: @JonStirling yes you are right.

Comment: @PeterDarmis  i tried the full code and gives this error                  Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\myChild\adminPages\affiche\affVaccinEnfant.php on line 18 i want to show a capture but don't know where to put it

Comment: @bigginerEngeneer change `$query` with `$sql` in `mysqli_prepare` and retry i had the query named differently. If it gives an error too then check if you connect to the db

Comment: still the same error @PeterDarmis i already changed that when i tried first time and the db is connected, i don't get the error really is there a relation ship whith the table columns type or somethings because my code i tried it for other table and it worked

Comment: this might sound silly @bigginerEngeneer is `enfant` table empty?

Comment: no there is 7 rows in the table !!!! that's really confusing

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){
        //execute query
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        //bind results
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $enfant_vacc_id, $enfant_id, $nomVaccin, $ageApproprie, $etat, 
        $date_vaccin); 
        //store result so num rows can be counted
        $r = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $result = array();
        //fetch results 
        while (mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
        array_push($result,array(
            "enfant_vacc_id"=>$enfant_vacc_id,
            "enfant_id"=>$enfant_id,
            "nomVaccin"=>$nomVaccin,
            "ageApproprie"=>$ageApproprie,
            "etat"=>$etat,
            "date_vaccin"=>$date_vaccin
        ));
        }
        //Displaying the array in json format w samineh result itableau fi json format 5ater valeur mta3 notre TAG_JSON_ARRAY hia result
    echo json_encode(array('resultVaccinEnf'=>$result));
    mysqli_close($con); 
    }
    else {
    // Error 
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $db->error);
    }
```

Comment: i tried the script you provided and it gave me this error

Comment: if the error starts with `Prepared Statement Error:` then it is the problem you search.

Comment: no no @ Peter Darmis it was that the error                                            Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\myChild\adminPages\affiche\affVaccinEnfant.php on line 18  is there somewhere i can put the screen shot